# Firebase does multiple calls even with if/else statement JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I am building an app with Vue and also Firebase. I am new to Firebase and i've some problems with it. I try to store names + emails in the database. What I want is to check first if the email is already in the database and if not, run another function that will store the name + email. If the email is stored in the database I would like to output an alert and cancel the submit.

So the check of the email in the database is going quite well, it will output an alert, and also I am able to retrieve the data. But where the problem lays is that when I enter an email that is not in the database. When I enter a new email (and name) it will check the database and return false but then right away does another call (I dont know why, that's the problem I guess) and it will return true, and the alert of already being there, at the same time. Then it will proceed to another function to store the data because that was the output of the first call (which was false).

My JS code:

```
checkForm() {

        let app = this;

        if (this.name == '' || this.emailadress == '') {
            alert('You have to fill out the form');
        } else {

            app.getFirebase();

        }
},

getFirebase() {

        let app = this;

        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/aanmeldingen/');
        ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

            const array = [];

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              var checkEmail = childSnapshot.val().email;
              array.push(checkEmail);
            });

            const res = array.includes(app.emailadress);
            console.log(array);
            console.log(res);

              if(res) {
                alert('You already have entered the giveaway');
              } else if (res == false) {

                app.store();

              }
        });
},

store() {
                this.step_two = false;
                this.active_two = false;

                this.active_three = true;
                this.step_three = true;

                let app = this;

                firebase.database().ref('/aanmeldingen/').push({
                username: app.name,
                email: app.emailadress,
                });
}
```

Screenshot of console (entered Jane, not in the database)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) instead of [on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on). `on()` leaves the listener attached, so when you push data in `store()` the listener fires again.